# How can I accurately convert 2017-09-29T19:00:00-0500 to mysql datetime?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

API request is returning date & time appointment info formatted as `2017-09-29T19:00:00-0500` and I want to save it in **mysql** as a **datetime** and preserve the correct am or pm of appointment.  How can I achieve this?

Here is my current code, which is not doing what I want.

```
$myvalue = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($field->values));
```

Comment: `$myvalue = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($field->values)); ` us e `H` it contain 24 hours format

Comment: mysql saved this as 2017-09-29 07:00:00

Comment: @MikeVolmar - why woudn't it, the format you're getting includes a timezone offset from GMT..... what timezone do you want to use for the value that you're saving in MySQL?

Comment: _“and preserve the correct am or pm of appointment”_ - `19:00:00` is neither `am` nor `pm` ... and those suffixes have nothing to do with the value you _store_ anyways; they are simply _formatting_ you apply when the value is output in a specific context.

Comment: MySQL does not save the datetime value in any particular (human readable) format.